# Progression of Matrix Columns

Tags: code-golf, matrix

Consider the infinite matrix:

```
0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1
0  0  2  3  0  0  2  3  0  0  2  3  0  0  2  3
0  0  0  4  5  6  0  0  0  4  5  6  0  0  0  4 ...
0  0  0  0  7  8  9 10  0  0  0  0  7  8  9 10
0  0  0  0  0 11 12 13 14 15  0  0  0  0  0 11
              ...
```

Each new row of the matrix is constructed by starting with `z` zeros, where `z` is the length of positive digits we're using in that row. The positive digits are constructed by starting with `1` and incrementing and adding an additional digit each time you iterate rows. That pattern is repeated infinitely to the right. So, for example, the first row starts `0, 1, 0, 1...` while the second row starts `0,0, 2,3, 0,0, 2,3...`. Following the pattern, the third row starts `0,0,0, 4,5,6, 0,0,0, 4,5,6...`.

Given two integers as input, `n` and `x`, output the first (top-most) `x` numbers of the `n`th column of the above matrix. (You can choose 0- or 1-indexing for the columns, just specify which in your submission.)

For example, for input `n = 0` (0-indexed), the column is entirely `0`s, so the output would just be `x` `0`s.

For input `n = 15` and `x = 6`, the output would be `[1, 3, 4, 10, 11, 0]`.

For input `n = 29` and `x = 15`, the output would be `[1, 0, 6, 8, 15, 0, 0, 34, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120]`.

For input `n = 99` and `x = 25`, the output would be `[1, 3, 4, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 37, 55, 56, 0, 87, 93, 0, 0, 151, 163, 176, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 325]`.

### I/O and Rules

- The input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- The input and output can be assumed to fit in your language's native number type.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(n)(x)`.

```javascript
n=>g=x=>x?[...g(x-1),n/x&1&&n%x+x*~-x/2+1]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i7dtsLWrsI@Wk9PL12jQtdQUydPv0LNUE0tT7VCu0KrTrdC30jbMNYqOvZ/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoahqaaGmaZeVn5mnoa6joK6piYXqgIjS02QIjwqLIEqjFBV/AcA)

#### How?

We use a direct formula to get the value of the cell at column **n** (0-indexed) and row **x** (1-indexed):

```javascript
n / x & 1 &&     // is this cell zero or non-zero?
n % x +          // column modulo row --> increment for a non-zero value at this position
x * ~-x / 2 + 1  // minimum value of non-zero values for this row:
                 // ∑(i=1...x-1)(i) + 1 = x(x - 1) / 2 + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>80</s> 76 bytes

Thanks to @JayCe for pointing out a bug!

```r
function(n,x)for(a in 1:x)print(rep(c(rep(0,a),((y=sum(1:a))-a+1):y),,n)[n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcRBCoAgEAXQq7icTyNo0EbqJNFCJMFFo1iBnt6gt3h1RLXqEV8JT8pCwg0xV/IqibKuodQkD9WzUPg37MFEfbvfi6zzgPaThetgFuxyYESyxvC8YHw)

Uses 1-based indexing for `n`. Very likely a golfier algorithm exists but `rep` is the enabler for the naive solution.

Comment: It errors for `n=1` since the result of sapply in no longer a matrix. [this fix](https://tio.run/##PckxCoRAEETRq4hRF5bgGIqeZDFoxAFB20FXsE8/uyYmP3j/yLHo6xwvm77LbmK86cOpKa0uobv5Hn382v6owDEnmeRpQwXFa60COgdpAMollmJ9S6d/jCNy/gE) is costly I wonder if there is a golfier one?

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right. Well, luckily there is one!

Comment: The for loop, yeah! And you golfed 4 bytes in the process :)

Comment: @JayCe yeah my original thought was to index the outermost `rep` with an `n` inside the `sapply`, which saved a byte, but then I remembered that `for` loops are shorter than `sapply` since I wouldn't have to define a function.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 69 bytes

```python
n,x=input()
a=i=1
exec"print(([0]*i+range(a,a+i))*n)[n];a+=i;i+=1;"*x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExCsAgDADAvc9wMupQhQ4ieYk4hCJtllTEgn29vWvfuB8Ja4mbyNLeoWEjZPRbnfVUrbMMrfNeDNtOclVNjiwDGIEsJZFFTmzRJ2XmWjG6cPw)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>27</s> <s>24</s> 23 bytes

-1 thanks to @FrownyFrog

```apl
⊢∘⍳(<×(+\⊣)--){+\⍵/2}|⊣
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TUw7CsJAEO1ziukSkeDsrpu44lFsghIJBiJqI5pKET9EbERb9QhqY@tN5iJxElHkwfDm/YJB7HYnQZz03E4cjEZRJ6fdIUpoucc85EubC61OlN2c1uvoVNu0uVZctzJllj1qMp2xkOdjTk5ZoPV5WJbmYY2yZ9NO@jZtF3YYRLHNAkeGqYUgEGDMl7I7WkKDV76goF5YQgBa0gAbhYpsN4oHGaoOypTsAyHRMgak/g3gN8phH7QG7TFt@GDUp6EFCE@B8L2/HSX1Gw)

Comment: 1 shorter {+\⍵/2}|⊣

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>25</s> 18 bytes

```
x:"@:t~ys:b@-)h1G)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8JKycGqpK6y2CrJQVczw9Bd8/9/QzMuMwA)

*Thanks to Luis Mendo for golfing out 6 bytes!*

This is essentially a MATL port of my R answer.

```
x		 % implicit input, read n and delete
:		 % implicit input, read x and push [1..x]
"		 % for loop with i = 1..x
 @:		 % push [1..i]
   t		 % duplicate
    ~		 % logical negate, turn to array of zeros
		 % stack: [[1..i], [0 .. (i times)]]
     y		 % duplicate from below
		 % stack: [[1..i], [0 .. (i times)], [1..i]]
      s:	 % sum and range
		 % stack: [[1..i], [0 .. (i times)], [1..(i * (i + 1)/2)]]
	b	 % bubble up
		 % stack: [[0 .. (i times)], [1..(i * (i + 1)/2)], [1..i]]
	 @-	 % push i and subtract. This will be used as a modular index to get the last i elements
		 % stack: [[0 .. (i times)], [1..(i * (i + 1)/2)], [1-i..0]]
	   )	 % index into array modularly to get the last i elements
		 % stack: [[0 .. (i times)], [(i-1)*i/2 + 1, .. (i * (i + 1)/2)]]
	    h	 % horizontally concatenate the array
	     1G) % push n and index modularly, leaving the result on the stack
		 % implicit end of for loop. The stack now contains the appropriate elements in order
		 % implicit end. Print stack contents
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ṖS+R¬;$)⁹ịⱮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//4bmWUytSwqw7JCnigbnhu4visa7///82/zE2)

-1 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

Argument 1: **x**
Argument 2: **n + 1**

Comment: `0ṁ;Ɗ` -> `¬;$` saves a byte.

Comment: @JonathanAllan And I suspect that's not yet enough. At least I removed the humiliating `’R`...(that is, at least for me) The weird thing is that during the last few days I've been thinking of the Thue-Morse sequence (which, in Jelly, contains `;¬$`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 14 bytes

```
↑!Tzo¢+MRN0CNN
```

The argument `n` (first) is 1-indexed, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbRMWQqvxDi7R9g/wMnP38/v//b2j23wwA)

Alternatively we could use [`↑!TṠzo¢+†K0CNN`](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr///ihpEhVOG5oHpvwqIr4oCgSzBDTk7///8xNv82) for the same number of bytes.

#### Explanation

```
↑!Tz(¢+)MRN0CNN -- example inputs n=4, x=3
            C N -- cut the natural numbers: [1,2,3,4,…]
             N  -- | using the natural numbers
                -- : [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10],…]
        M N     -- map over the naturals
         R 0    -- | replicate 0 that many times
                -- : [[0],[0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],…]
   z(  )        -- zip these two lists
      +         -- | concatenate
     ¢          -- | cycle
                -- : [[0,1,0,1,…],[0,0,2,3,0,0,2,3,…],…]
  T             -- transpose: [[0,0,0,0,…],[1,0,0,0,…],[0,1,0,0,…],[1,3,4,0,…],…]
 !              -- index into that list using n: [1,3,4,0,…]
↑               -- take x: [1,3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
↑mȯ!⁰¢§+`R0§…ȯ→Σ←ΣN
```

Takes arguments as `n` (1-indexed), then `x`.
Saved 2 bytes thanks to BMO, but still not as short as BMO's answer.
My first attempt at using Husk.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9odXNr///ihpFtyK8h4oGwwqLCpytgUjDCp@KApsiv4oaSzqPihpDOo07///8xNv82)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://github.com/ngn/k), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
{(a>i)*(+\i)-i-a:(2*1+i:!y)!'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLCoMwEEX3/YoRSmsUIZOYaDLQH7GCbizBYkFc@MD@ug3aQpnNuTNnbpt0j27bGruE9c2xKIzvjiUuqW0oIoydDSYWXMd1G@xyLuZ3b5tipKmk6tVSWDW1e5LPNFPPyvU0FJyQ0wV56RkVaUKQkAJyQIR9Kwz5gw@gIQdUHjjIFKTZ6RgUu2sMCfWt4D/X2xkoBUp7zDMw8nhRCKglYKb/iqRQ5fYB)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 75 bytes

```hs
u!v=take v[cycle((0<$l)++l)!!u|n<-[1..],l<-[take n$drop(sum[1..n-1])[1..]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3fCoIwHEZf5Sd4sWGODLpQpjd12xPYiOFGDfePbRpB777Mu8P5DnwvHmepdVbGu5DgyhMnN2edEoAA0QEDzkux9onPEtZx@kxaInSkpcZVpXFRLF9L67EhhB30BntnSxGcR3Ex/8HWDcN7wVg2XFnowQdlExBAd7R0a/fAUA@w/eDNGe4hSC42fLsgIvSUwlOmi7NJ2hRz28Lp/AM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
lambda n,x:[n/y%2*(n%y+y*~-y/2+1)for y in range(1,x+1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1LDoJADIb3nqIbEh410BlnYEw4CbLAKEqiAyEsmI1Xx0qEYEzaxdf@j84N99aKqc5P06N6ni8VWByPhY2dJ0Lfei5y4WvvYhFRULc9OGgs9JW9XX3CkY/l1PWNHaD2SaEO8rwgBIlwQKCElykpd4tGGCT1FfFXI2SsUTPwSHZJs9A6JDYRxqBQPz3JNuKTkiIoPig9Y8Zo5Jql2EeamVL91ySFKqc3)

Developed independently; but I note that this ends up being a port of [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s Javascript answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 52 bytes

```perl
/ /;say+(((0)x$_,($.+=--$_)..$.+$_)x$`)[$`]for 1..$'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fQd@6OLFSW0NDw0CzQiVeR0NFT9tWV1clXlNPD8gE0hUqCZrRKgmxaflFCoZAQfX//40sFQxN/@UXlGTm5xX/1/U11TMwNPivmwcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 25 bytes

```
LO©LsL£¹£¹LÅ0s)øε˜®Ì∍}ø¹è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fx//QSp9in0OLD@0EYZ/DrQbFmod3nNt6es6hdYd7HnX01h7ecWjn4RX//xtZchmaAgA)

---

05AB1E goes with matrices like toothpaste and orange juice, but not a bad byte-count considered how bad my implementation is. Even my code is laughing at me "`LO©L`".

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
ＩＥ…·¹Ｎ§⁺Ｅι⁰ＥιＬ⊞Ｏυωη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBCsIwEEX3niLLCUSwC924ElcBq8EbjHFoCnEakkn19rEVV@/z@M8HzH7C2JrLIwucsQj0mMCyj7WMM92RB4LOKMupyrW@HpRBa6NOYvlJH3DL75eMRu0W/58X4kECuFrCLVFGmTJUo95ar3FYcWztsOn2bTvHLw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    ¹               Literal 1
     Ｎ              First input (`x`) as a number
  …·                Inclusive range
 Ｅ                  Map (value `i`, 0-indexed counter `k`)
         ι          Current value
        Ｅ           Map over implicit range
          ⁰         Literal 0 (i.e. create array of `i` zeros)
            ι       Current value
           Ｅ        Map over implicit range
                 ω  Arbitrary variable
                υ   Predefined array
              ⊞Ｏ    Push
             Ｌ      Length
       ⁺            Concatenate arrays
      §           η Index by second input (`n`)
Ｉ                   Cast to string and implicitly print on separate lines
```

The snippet `ＥιＬ⊞Ｏυω` generates the next `i` integers by the expedient of pushing a dummy value to an array each pass through the loop and taking the length of the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>65</s> <s>63</s> 60 bytes

```java
n->x->{for(;x>0;)System.out.println(n/x%2*(n%x+x*--x/2+1));}
```

`n` is 0-indexed, `x` is 1-indexed, outputs the numbers new-line delimited and reversed.

Port of [*@Arnauld's JavaScript (ES6) answer*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164909/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bY9Ba8MwDIXv@xW6FOzWcZtACyFrLoXBDjv1OHbwUqc4SxQTK8Wl5Ldn7pqxDgpGWNLjvU@VOqmoOnyNRa2cgzdl8PIE4EiRKaAKW9mTqWXZY0GmRfkyfZ5fkfRRd@KRaNei6xvd/YryHErYjhjlPsovZduxzOerjO/PjnQj256k7QxSjQyXfpbMGc78ws@jyC@TRcx5NoxZwArP9p91IJsAT605QBOg2Z6CwfH9AxS/HgBA2hFbiTXP/tp4LTb3fZKK@J8gTUVyGwy3uPucH0WgBBTX6qegUipr6zNDLlVRaEvMT5YPzpu8h/Eb)
A pretty-printed result in correct order is <s>8</s> 6 bytes longer: [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jU/BaoNAEL33KwYhsBvXTRQSkK0eCz30lGPpYZtoWGtGWUfZEPx2u6lC01thGN6becx7U@lBR9XpazrWuuvgTRu8PQF0pMkcofJb2ZOpZdnjkUyD8mUBz69Ixbmw4n@iA1mD5zyHErIJo9xF@W3QFmwWBKpsLFMu3ypuM9y4VbJmuHKhW0eR2yRhzMMAgtAqW1BvEawaJ@VD@mr7z9rnXOIOjTnBxb/AZrv3D9D8/g4AFR2xrdhx9Uvjndg/8iQV8R9BmopkHoyz3aPPj8IgAYp7d4vR4dpRcZFNT7L1GahGVkrdtvWVIV@A48vRcfoG)

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 67 bytes

```
i#l=cycle((++)=<<(0<$)$[i..l-1]):l#(l+l-i+1)
n!x=take x$(!!n)<$>1#2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TchBC8IgGAbg@37FK34HRTZSMFhofyQ6yBKSfbmoHdavt7rtOT739J4zc2tFcpw@E2eljNExBHUIpOlShoF7e9UnlooN98VY3VWxxTXNGRspIaoOdLbStUcqFRG3pQPwfJW6gmA9BHDclxt/Zf2@xn85374)

```
i#l                  -- function # builds the infinite matrix
                     -- input: i and l are lowest and highest+1 non-zero number of
                     -- the current line
   = cycle           -- for the current line, repeat infinitely
           [i..l-1]  --   the non-zero numbers of the line appended 
     (++)=<<(0<$)    --   to a list of 0s with the same length
   :                 -- append next row of the matrix
     l#(l+l-i+1)     --   which is a recursive call with i and l adjusted

n!x =                -- main function
              1#2    -- create matrix
      (!!n)<$>       -- pick nth element of each row
  take x             -- take the first x numbers thereof
```